# Animation "fade1" works but not "fade0"

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Trying to add animation to "Forgot Password?" element in JS.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`button`).forEach(btn =>
  btn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    if (btn.id === 'login-btn') {
      forgotPassword.classList.add("fade1");
      forgotPassword.classList.remove("fade0");
      submitLoginInfo.textContent = "Log In";
    } else {
      forgotPassword.classList.add("fade0");
      forgotPassword.classList.remove("fade1");
      submitLoginInfo.textContent = "Sign Up";
    }
  })
);
```

```css
.fade0 {
    animation: 1s fadeAway ease-out forwards;
}
.fade1 {
    animation: 1s fadeIn ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeAway {
    from {opacity: 1};
    to {opacity: 0};
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0};
    to {opacity: 1};
}
```

```html
<h1 id="submitLoginInfo">-</h1>
<div id="forgotPassword">thing</div>
<button id="login-btn">fadein</button>
<button id="not-login-button">fadeout</button>
```

Adding fade1 class works as expected, the animations plays every time the login button is activated. But the fading out animation of the message doesn't work. Any clue? (full code: https://justpaste.it/g5k2a)

Comment: I've turned your code into a runnable snippet, and it works fine?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you sure about that? It doesn't fade out for me in Chrome

Comment: Ah, that would be why. I only checked on Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give your items any target opacity. Add the target opacity to the class definition otherwise opacity is already 1, and your telling it to animate from 1 to 1

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`button`).forEach(btn =>
  btn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    if (btn.id === 'login-btn') {
      forgotPassword.classList.add("fade1");
      forgotPassword.classList.remove("fade0");
      submitLoginInfo.textContent = "Log In";
    } else {
      forgotPassword.classList.add("fade0");
      forgotPassword.classList.remove("fade1");
      submitLoginInfo.textContent = "Sign Up";
    }
  })
);
```

```css
.fade0 {
    animation: 1s fadeAway ease-out forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade1 {
    animation: 1s fadeIn ease-in-out forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes fadeAway {
    from {opacity: 1};
    to {opacity: 0};
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0};
    to {opacity: 1};
}
```

```html
<h1 id="submitLoginInfo">-</h1>
<div id="forgotPassword">thing</div>
<button id="login-btn">fadein</button>
<button id="not-login-button">fadeout</button>
```

Comment: the keyframes tells the browser to animate "from" a value "to" a value, you do not need to set an initial value

Comment: @mattrichards `@keyframes` only tells the browser *how* to animate when certain properties are changed. It's still up to you to actually *apply the change* to the properties. You should *always* be setting your initial and target values in the CSS directly.

Comment: ok point accepted, if the from/to value is not the computed style then yes, they do need to be set for when the animation ends